# is there a way to get length of a string in Neo4j cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

pretty simple question, 
is there a way to get length of a string in Neo4j cypher?
  I cannot find any document for that.

thanks

Answer (score 28):

To return the length of a string in Cypher, use the `SIZE()` function. The `LENGTH()` function is now exclusively used for measuring PATHs in the graph.

`RETURN size("This is an example string")`

yields 25

From the good folks at Neo: "This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. Using `length` on anything that is not a path is deprecated, please use `size` instead"

Answer (score 8):

Try `length()`, like

```
RETURN length("hello world")
```

in 2.0 (return-only queries are new in 2.0) or

```
START n=node(5)
RETURN length(n.name)
```

or some such for 1.9.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [length() scalar function](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-length) like:

```
MATCH (n:Crew)-[r:KNOWS*]-m 
WHERE n.name='Neo' 
RETURN n AS Neo,r,m,length(n.name)
```

Check out this example [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=string_length).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you read the [manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-length). It has all of the information you need.

To return or filter on the length of a string, use the LENGTH() function.
For example:

```
Return Length("Test !")
```

result will be 6.